# how to scope order in a HABTM association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have two models:

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :branches
end

class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :doctors
end
```

I want to order the list of doctors(index action) by the branch name either ASC or Desc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the HABTM association works differently than any other one-to-many would in this context, so you'd use `select()`, `group()`, and `order()`, probably something like this:

```
@doctors = Doctor.joins(:branches).group('doctors.id').order('max(branches.name)')
```

Naturally, you'll need to choose how to aggregate this - a Doctor can have many Branches, so you'll have to specify which name to use in the ordering - `max()` may not be the correct aggregate function for your needs.

Note that this will exclude any Doctor models that don't have *any* associated Branches, since the default for `joins` is to use an inner join. If you don't want to do that, you'll probably have to write the `joins` out manually, so that it uses left joins instead of inner joins, like so:

```
joins('left join branches_doctors on doctors.id = branches_doctors.doctor_id left join branches on branch.id = branches_doctors.branch_id')
```

The default name for  a HABTM join table is the plural form of both models in alphabetical order (hence `branches_doctors`, rather than `doctors_branches`).